# MacBook Air charging light stays amber and does not go green and machine does not boot or even chime

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, charging, power

I have an 11" MacBook Air 6,1 from mid 2013 that I found discarded and had restored but now seems dead again.

I got the machine with a broken screen backlight and missing SSD. I took it to the Genius Bar and they diagnosed only those two problems. I attached it to an external monitor and USB 3.0 hard drive and installed El Capitan and used it for a couple of days. Everything worked except the webcam. Though the machine had sat for several weeks with no power before I acquired it the battery life turned out to be very good.

I put it to sleep when the battery charge indicator had just gone red and did not have access to a charger/power supply for over a day.

When I was able to borrow a friend's power supply the light did not come on. After finding another Mac user we plugged each other's Magsafe into each other's machines and both lights came on. When I went back to the first charger on my machine the light then stayed amber but the machine would not boot and would not even make the startup "chime" sound. I kept it plugged in all day yesterday and the charger light never went green.

I tried resetting the EMC to no avail. I can't seem to find information on this specific problem online. I can't get a reservation at the Genius Bar for another five days.

Comment: For sure a hardware problem. Since you can't access Apple Diagnostics, you're probably SOL. Book something with the geniuses or a 3rd party repair group.

Comment: After another couple of days without a charger I just borrowed one again and it's gone back to no light at all.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar thing happen to my old Macbook. I discharged the battery all the way down and then couldn't recharge it for about two days. When I finally could charge it, it wouldn't charge or turn on. It turned out to be the battery. You can probably get a replacement battery from Apple (if it turns out to be the battery), but I found cheaper options on Amazon.

Comment: Hmm I didn't think mine went all the way down as I put it in sleep mode just after it got to the red "low batter" area. I would've put it in hibernate mode but it seems Macs don't have such a mode so I assumed it would automatically go from sleep to hibernate either after a period of time or when the battery got to some specific low threshold to trigger it.
Also when I got the MacBook it had not been plugged in for at least three weeks when I first tried to see if it would work. At that time it couldn't have been hibernating or sleeping since it had no disk and no OS.

Comment: I depleted the battery several times in the course of owning my old Macbook, and one day, it just didn't recover. I can't say for certain it is your battery. I can only say that I experienced something similar and the battery was the culprit.